# Jquery Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Why do I get this error and how can I test for it so it wont break, I tried checking for null but obviously that wont work, thanks.

Please don't advice to not write the ID like this as I know its wrong but it is a possibility.

```
var jsonTest = [
  {
    "myId": "''''''\"\"\"\"'''''''''''''\"#####$'''''",
  }
];

alert(jsonTest[0].myId); 
// Works - alerts the myId

$('#' + jsonTest[0].myId ).length; 
// Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
// #''''''""""'''''''''''''"#####$'''''
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

jQuery's uses this code to detect an id based selector :

```
characterEncoding = "(?:\\\\.|[\\w-]|[^\\x00-\\xa0])+"
...
"ID": new RegExp( "^#(" + characterEncoding + ")" ),
```

This regex fails for `"''''''\"\"\"\"'''''''''''''\"#####$'''''"` or more simply for `"'"`.

The query engine is limited, which isn't very surprising for a so concise language and id validity rules so lax. it can't handle any valid id.

If you really need to be able to handle any kind of valid id, use

```
$(document.getElementById(jsonTest[0].myId))
```

In fact, you should never use `$('#'+id)` as it simply adds a useless (and a little dangerous) layer of parsing for the same operation.

Comment: Hashes escaping might also help.

Comment: @VisioN It wouldn't be enough.

Comment: Thanks dystroy  that's an awesome solution

Answer (score 8):

If I understood your question, you have an ID that contains special characters. You basically [need to escape them](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) so they're treated as literal characters rather than query selectors:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

... and in this case you also need an additional escaping level for the string delimiter, `"`. It's crazy but this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
jQuery(function($){
    console.log( $("#" + "\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\\"\\\"\\\"\\\"\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\\"\\#\\#\\#\\#\\#\\$\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'").length );
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="''''''&quot;&quot;&quot;&quot;'''''''''''''&quot;#####$'''''">Foo</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Of course, dystroy's answer —omit jQuery selection engine and use `getElementByID()`— is way more practical. jQuery manual [links an interesting blog entry](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) that covers this and other related techniques:

> document.getElementById() and similar functions like
>   document.getElementsByClassName() can just use the unescaped attribute
>   value, the way it’s used in the HTML. Of course, you would have to
>   escape any quotes so that you still end up with a valid JavaScript
>   string.

Answer (score 4):

W3C has defined a new function for this this: [`CSS.escape()`](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes). In your example code, it would look like this:

```
var jsonTest = [
  {
    "myId": "''''''\"\"\"\"'''''''''''''\"#####$'''''",
  }
];

$('#' + CSS.escape(jsonTest[0].myId)).length; // Works
```

Browsers don't yet support it, but there is a polyfill library that you can use in the mean time:
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape

I've used it with success in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error while **upgrading from jquery 1.6 to jquery 3.6**.
I got this error in **flexigrid library**. The fix to this problem is simple as mentioned in above answers.

**You need to escape all special characters and unescape them** if needed to show in a grid or for further processing.

The code looks like:

```
var str = "abc@abc.com";

//make str value to, basically escape all special chars : "abc/@abc/.com"
str = str.replace(/[.*+?^$@%{}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');

//do some processing

//revert str value to: "abc@abc.com"
str = str.replaceAll("\\", "");
```