# Javascript composite component id with colons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some composite component, and i am trying to bind some jquery events on his childrens. The most important is that i want to bind event for each input of this selectoneradio, thoose inputs gets name after selectoneradio id, unfortunetly this id can contains ':'. I replace : for \: but it always says that

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=form1\\:j_idt47\\:radioSelect]
```

code:

```
cc:implementation>
        <h:selectOneRadio id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
                          value="#{cc.attrs.value}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}">

            <cc:insertChildren/>
        </h:selectOneRadio>

<script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var name = '#{cc.clientId}:#{cc.attrs.id}'.replace(/:/g,'\\\\:');
        jQuery('input[name=' + name + ']').click(function() {
            console.log("click");
        });
        /* ]]> */
</script>
```

in place of < cc:insertChildren/> there ll be random number of < f:selectItem> or even < f:selectItems>

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing them like:

```
$('[id='+ID+']')

or

$('[id=ID]')
```

Comment: ID? should i make some variable for that. If yes how can i get thoose ID ? And i edited  a little bit code.

Comment: would be great if you can create some fiddle with dom

Comment: also see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338727/jquery-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression

Comment: maybe i just, ask bad question, how simple find all input type radio for specific selectOneRadio ?

Comment: I think i found solution, problem was here replace(/:/g,'\\\\:');
it should be replace(":","\\:");