# jQuery select button with "weird" id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following button and I need to select it with jQuery.

```
<button class="btn btn-success hlavni" id="images/532721abc9c9e/532721b43b475.jpeg" type="button" onclick="return hlavni(this.id)">
    <span>Nastavit jako hlavní</span>
</button>
```

I tried this:

```
$('#images/532721abc9c9e/532721b43b475.jpeg').id("newID");
```

And also this:

```
$('button[id=images/532721abc9c9e/532721b43b475.jpeg]').id("newID");
```

Both throws "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression".
Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Do you need to select it by ID?

Comment: Someone obviously added the wrong text in the wrong place, as that shouldn't be an ID

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Syntax error, unrecognized expression:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338727/jquery-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression)

Answer (score 6):

You could escape the slashes but the best solution, both faster and more reliable, when your id is dynamically passed, is to use

```
$(document.getElementById('images/532721abc9c9e/532721b43b475.jpeg'))
```

This being said, such an id isn't really good practice. It makes everything harder, especially css. It's probable you could build a simpler id.

If the goal is to set a new id, no need to use jQuery, simply do

```
document.getElementById('images/532721abc9c9e/532721b43b475.jpeg').id = "newID";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape special characters `/` and `.` with two backslashes as well as using **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to set new `id` of your button:

```
$('#images\\/532721abc9c9e\\/532721b43b475\\.jpeg').attr('id', 'newID');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BTSFg/)**