# Syntax error, unrecognized expression on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project where i have an issue with the commenting function i've made. Whenever i comment and use special characters the console displays this error: `syntax error, unrecognized expression`. Furthermore the request goes through and my backend (PHP) inserts the data to the DB but i then have to refresh to get the updated version of the post with that new comment. I can't figure out why even after a couple of searches here on stack and i could really use a new pair of eyes on the code.

I figure that the backend isn't the issue which is why it's left out of this post. Furthermore the form just contains a text input and a submit button. It might be important to mention that i use jQuery v3.3.1.

Finally when the form is submitted an ajax call gets triggered. Here it is:

```
var newComment;
$(document).on("submit", "form[data-comment]", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var where = $(this);
    var updateThis = $(where).parent().parent();
    var data = $(where).attr("data-comment").split(",");
    var comment = $(where).find("input[name='commenter']").val().toString();// <= this might be the issue?

    if (data[0] == 1){
        if (data[1] != "" && data[2] != "" && data[3] != ""){
            //insert comment via ajax and return post and insert post
            if (newComment){ <= prevent firing until newComment = false
                newComment.abort();
                return false;
            }

            $(where).find("input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", true);
            $(where).find("input[type='submit']").val("commenting...");

            newComment = $.ajax({
                url: "mypage/core/AjaxRequests.php", <= call to php handler
                type: "POST",
                data: { type: "15", data: data, comment: comment }
            });
            $(comment).val("");

            newComment.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){

                newComment = false;
                $(where).find("input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", false);
                $(where).find("input[type='submit']").val("Comment");

                if (response.length > 200){
                    $(updateThis).parent().fadeTo(0,0);
                    $(updateThis).parent().prop('outerHTML', response);
                    $(updateThis).parent().fadeTo(1,1);
                }
            }); 
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: .prop('outerHTML', response);  <-- why? Why are you not using .html()??

Comment: Because the response is just an "updated" version of the post that also contains the comment. I know it might have been easier to just prepend it but in the future i would like to implement a comment like function that needs some encrypted code from the backend

Comment: Cause i need the element including the element itself in order to display it correctly

Comment: A bunch of well placed console logs should tell you where the issue is happening. Apart from that, maybe you should wrap comment with encodeURIComponent in your ajax request:`comment: encodeURIComponent(comment)` - and data as well since it looks like they're both strings

Comment: `var where = $(this)`  it's already a jQuery object at this stage, no need to use `$(where)` later on

Comment: @KaiQing nope. When using a `data` object, jQuery automatically encodes all the keys and values

Comment: The issue is definitely this line ~ `$(comment).val("");` since `comment` is the string value of your text input and not a jQuery selector. **Voting to close as a typo**

Comment: @Phil i will just have a look at it. I just find it odd that it works without special characters...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Syntax error, unrecognized expression:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338727/jquery-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression)

Comment: The exclamation mark makes it fail jQuery's selector validation, simple as that. Try it yourself ~ `jQuery('div!')`. I don't even know what you're trying to do with `$(comment).val('')`, it makes no sense. Did you mean `where.find("input[name='commenter']").val('')`?

Comment: the issue was as Phil said a typo $(comment).val("");

Comment: So replace() the element instead of using prop.